Can anyone identify this early biplane from 1920?
The photo was taken in August, 1920, and I believe it was taken in France.

The plane nosedived just after this photo was taken (I have 3 other photos showing the wreck). The crash didn't look terrible, as it doesn't seem it actually took off, but 'tripped' on a railroad track during taxi.
Call letters on the side read "F-ADAY", and I think it's a Farman F.60 Goliath, but I can't confirm that. What do the call letters mean?
Also, would there be any way to find out more about this specific aircraft?

You're right, it's a Farman F.60 Goliath. It was used by the French airline Cie Messageries Aériennes (CMA), to carry both passengers, mail and freight.

CMA
CMA was founded by Bréguet (aircraft manufacturer), other shareholders being Blériot (aircraft engineer and inventor, first to cross the Channel), Renault (founder of Renault automobile manufacture) and Caudron (aircraft manufacturer, later merged into Renault).

Source.
The airline was based at Le Bourget aerodrome and had initially a service with Lille (north of France), but exended quickly to Croydon (London, UK) to compete with Farman airlines, then Bruxelles (Belgium) and Amsterdam (Netherlands). After several mergers, it would be a part of Air France, created in 1933 to compete with the KLM created in 1920 and the larger Deutsche Lutf Hansa created in 1926.
F-ADAY history
From this page in French:

Le Farman F.60 Goliath « F-ADAY », (c/n 6833/39) construit en 1920 et acquis par la Cie Messageries Aériennes (CMA), En octobre 1927 il est mis au nom d’Air-Union, après la fusion de la CMA et des Grands Express Aérien, avec le nom  “Alsace”. Le 24 mai 1926, il s’écrase en phase d’atterrissage près de Littlestone (Kent). En octobre 1927, l’avion est reconstruit et il devient un F.63bis. Il finit sa carrière comme avion postal et n’apparait plus sur les registres en octobre 1931.

in English:

Farman F.60 Goliath « F-ADAY », (c/n 6833/39) built in 1920, owned by Cie Messageries Aériennes (CMA), in October 1927 transferred to Air-Union, after the merge between CMA and Grands Express Aérien, under the name “Alsace”. On 24 May 1926, it crashed while approaching Littlestone (Kent). Rebuilt in October 1927 as a F.63bis. Ends its carrier as postal carrier and disappears from registers in October 1931.

From Flickr:

Photo by skylarkair.
This aircraft also appeared in the silent movie L'autre aile (watch it here).
Crashes

The crash didn't look terrible

From the insurance expert's report (August 1921):

Assessment of the airworthiness of F-ADAY Farman Goliath to return to Le Bourget for repair after temporary fixes following in which part of the undercarriage sank into a cover trench during take-off. It concludes that without further repairs on-site and trials the return flight would be at the owner's risk. Client: The White Cross Aviation Insurance Association.

After the May 1926 crash, it was rebuilt, improved as a F.63bis:

Source.
F-ADAY registration

what do the call letters [F-ADAY] mean?

It just happened to be the next sequential entry in the French register. F-AD prefix was used for year 1920, and CMA registered several aircraft: F-ADAT, F-ADAU, F-ADAV and F-ADAY.

Source.
More info

Also, would there be any way to find out more about this specific aircraft?

You can always search on the aircraft ID when it's available, it's the most efficient way. Corresponding results: From Bing and from Google.

Thank you! It's incredible how much info you knew or could get. I did web searching for hours, and came up with so little in comparison.

I just watched the movie, and I saw the F-ADAY twice.

One thing I'm confused about; it says in your French to English translated section that it was built in 1920, but the call letters indicate 1921 according to the call letter link you added. The negatives I have are dated as August 1920, and was taken on a world (European?) cruise. The photographer (great-great, or great-grandfather) had notes and years on each negative, so I feel certain the 1920 is correct. But why then would the call letters assigned be from 1921?

@KirkS: I noted this inconsistency. According to this 1984 magazine the aircraft was built in 1921. According to this 11/1922 publication, it entered into operations at CMA on 26/06/1921. The problem is errors are usually copy-pasted and propagate. If you need an official answer, it might possible to contact the French DGAC via their archive section.

@KirkS: Another source which seems more reliable, using the Véritas (insurance certification agency) register, the registration date is 1920 (p. 8).
